# Eliminating decimals without approximation

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression

Is there any way I can eliminate decimals without approximating the number?

Example:

```
 Value    | Desired output
 1.69     | 1
 2.12     | 2
 105.9999 | 105
```

I want to use the field calculator for this. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `floor(your number here)` does what you are looking for. For more details check [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#floor).

Comment: One thing to be aware of, though: If an integer is approximated by a float, e.g. `123455.99999999` for `123456`, using `floor()` will convert it to `123455`.